# CSS :hover flicker

Tags: html, css

I'm using the Bootstrap Card component with an image overlay that I would like appear over the image during mouseover.

After trying the solutions to similar problems on here and trying everything in the documentation, I can't get the overlay to not flicker on and off whilst the cursor is over the image. Any suggestions would be great thank you.

I have tried using display or opacity instead of visibility and selecting the containing div using :hover also didn't make a difference.

```css
.hidden-overlay {
  background-color: #222831;
  opacity: 80%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.card-title {
  color: #00adb5;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover + .hidden-overlay {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="card bg-dark text-white">
   <a href="https://codesandbox.io/README.md">
     <img
        class="card-img img-fluid"
        src="images\Keeper.png"
        alt="Keeper image"
      />
    </a>
    <div class="card-img-overlay hidden-overlay">
        <h5 class="card-title">Keeper</h5>
        <p class="card-text">React, Hooks, Material UI, ES6</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Once again, any ideas would be very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: use  0.1 to 1 value in  opacity instead of percentage.  

80% means opacity : 0.8;  try it!

Comment: I edited the post, and the code you provided doesn't replicate the problem so it must be something else, like an element partially cover the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are checking the hover state of sibling anchor tag to set the visibility of your `hidden-overlay`. So, when the overlay becomes visible and comes on top of the anchor element the anchor looses its hover and the flickr appears.

Just add the hover pseudo-class to the parent.

```
<div class="card bg-dark text-white wrapper">
```

and update your rule to

```
.wrapper:hover > .hidden-overlay {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```css
.hidden-overlay {
  background-color: #222831;
  opacity: 80%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.card-title {
  color: #00adb5;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.wrapper:hover > .hidden-overlay {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card bg-dark text-white wrapper">
   <a href="https://codesandbox.io/README.md">
     <img
        class="card-img img-fluid"
        src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"
        alt="Keeper image"
      />
    </a>
    <div class="card-img-overlay hidden-overlay">
        <h5 class="card-title">Keeper</h5>
        <p class="card-text">React, Hooks, Material UI, ES6</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using JS events to detect instead of CSS selectors. The flickering probably suggest that the element to expose partially covers the element that's listening for a hover event. Perhaps JS events could more robustly handle that case - `onMouseEnter`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I don't have much experience, especially with JS, so am trying to achieve as much of the effects with CSS as possible before I try things with JS.